# Error in state 4 of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I'm trying to create a MediaPlayer application. To implement the same I've created a service which plays the mp3 file in the MediaPlayer.
I'm getting a NullPointerException while opening the mp3 file.

The code to instantiate the media player is in onStartCommand() as shown below:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {        
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

The **handler implemented inside the service** sets the data source on the MediaPlayer and prepares it to play the song as shown below:

```
class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.INT_PLAY_SONG:
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    File file = new File(msg.getData().getString(Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG));
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, msg.getData().getString(Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG) represents the path for the mp3 file. Example for the same:
**/storage/extSdCard/Songs/yaara re.mp3**
This is the same path for the song inside my phone.

The path for mp3 file is taken from **MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA**

**Code to send message to service is added inside an Activity. The code is as follows:**

```
private void sendMessageToService(String stringPath) {
    Message message = Message.obtain(null, Constants.INT_PLAY_SONG, 0, 0);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG, stringPath);
    message.setData(bundle);
    try {
        messenger.send(message);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println("exception while sending message in messenger");
    }
}
```

**New stack trace**

```
    02-07 23:29:50.019    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: 0
    02-07 23:29:50.019    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
    02-07 23:29:50.029    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
    02-07 23:29:50.029    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource(55, 0, 576460752303423487)
    02-07 23:29:50.059    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
    02-07 23:29:50.059    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1411/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1411/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ New video size 0 x 0
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1411/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1411/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1399/com.varunk314.mymp3 I/MediaPlayer﹕ Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1412/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1412/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepared
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1412/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
    02-07 23:29:50.069    1399-1412/com.varunk314.mymp3 V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
```

OnPreparedListener is also implemented as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out the actual problem in my code.

Comment: where you are using `MyHandler` ?

Comment: MyHandler is inside my service.

Comment: show related code where you are adding data in Message?

Comment: did you try to remove the space in the filename ?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: code to send message to service has been added now.

Comment: @ Hacketo: no, not yet. Will try it right now and let you know the same here.

Comment: @ Hacketo: getting the same error even after removing all the spaces from the name of the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. the value of `msg.getData()` is `NULL`
2. the value of `msg.getData().getString(Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG)` is `NULL`

Attach a debugger or define some additional check to understand which is the real cause (1 or 2).

**UPDATE**: you are passing some parameters in the wrong order!
Change this:

```
bundle.putString(stringPath, Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG);
```

to this:

```
bundle.putString(Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG, stringPath);
```

This motivates the error at `java.io.File.fixSlashes` method, because `Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG` isn't a file name.

**UPDATE 2**
You need to call

```
mediaplayer.prepare()
```

instead of

```
prepareAsync()
```

if you want to play directly in the next line. The async method will trigger a dedicated callback when ready (which is the correct place to put the mediaplayer on start)

Comment: Have tried this out. Neither msg.getData() nor msg.getData().getString(Constants.STRING_BUNDLE_KEY_PLAY_SONG) is NULL.

Comment: Could you suggest me some additional checks to add in order to identify the problem.